# How to view Jupyter notebook in Pycharm pro *in standard layout*?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

When opening a Jupyter notebook in Pycharm pro, I have 3 options that I am aware of:

1. Editor only
2. Editor and preview
3. Preview only

Option 2 opens 2 windows (editor and preview), side by side.

I want the regular "browser" layout, where I can see a single window, in which a cell can be run, and its output is following.

Is that possible in Pycharm pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No, Pycharm does not support other modes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html#ui). I have also experimented myself with this and a couple plugins. There might be a good plugin out there, but for the now the best thing you can do is

1. use the editor+preview mode, and run from the editor (ctrl+enter) and see the output in the preview.
2. just use the browser, like I started doing after realizing Jupyter support for Pycharm is lacking

Comment: Taking away functionality from the user is really strange. I hope another answer will replace this one soon

Comment: @Gulzar Yeah, you could check out JetBrains' DataLore. It was built for Jupyter Notebook integration. I have not used it myself, so I cannot say exactly what features or modes it offers.

Comment: Jetbrains DataLore does feature 'normal' mode and the split mode known from PyCharm for JupyterNotebooks. Also, if switching from Jupyter kernel to DataLore kernel, it has the interesting feature 'ReactiveMode' which changes all dependent outcomes of your code as soon as you changed the code on-the-fly, e.g. refreshing a plot if you change the input numbers, or update the outputs of your functions if you change the function. (Has it limitations, but nice feature.)

Comment: Indeed, for multi-index it is not really convenient....